# Is there a MaxPosition function?

Tags: core-language

The `Max` and `Min` functions return values, but I would like to have the position(s). Is there a standard function that does this? Could not find one.

Comment: None that I know of but `Ordering[#, -1] &` might help.

Comment: @henrik Schumacher oke that is better then using position. Thx

Comment: If you know an upper bound, could do with `Nearest` as follows: `In[271]:= Nearest[{2, 1, 3, 8, 2, 8, 5} -> "Index", 1000]

Out[271]= {4, 6}`